# file upload using requests library in python

Tags: python

I have the following script that allows me to upload files to usersfiles. It does not work for large files (eg 1GB). What change could make?

```
import requests

import random

import re

filehandle = open("menu.avi", "rb")

resp=requests.get("https://usersfiles.com/")

sess_id = re.search('sess_id.*=?"(.*)?"', str(resp.text)).group(1)

srv_tmp_url = re.search('srv_tmp_url.*=?"(.*)?"', str(resp.text)).group(1)

upload_type = re.search('upload_type.*=?"(.*)?"', str(resp.text)).group(1)

UID = ''

for i in range(0, 12):

    UID = UID + '' + str(random.randint(0,10))

url2="https://up11.usersfiles.com/cgi-bin/upload.cgi?upload_id="+UID+"&js_on=1&utype=reg&upload_type="+upload_type

r = requests.post(url2, data={"upload_type":upload_type , "sess_id":sess_id,
                                "srv_tmp_url":srv_tmp_url}, files = {"file_0":filehandle})

link_usersfiles = re.search('name=.fn.>(.*?)<', str(r.text)).group(1)
```

This script generates me the error:

> body.write(data)
>
> MemoryError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default when uploading files, **`requests`** reads the entire file into memory, and so is liable to run out when uploading large files. The easiest way around this is to install **`requests-toolbelt`** which can easily stream file uploads.

For your example, you could use something like this:

```
import requests
from requests_toolbelt.multipart.encoder import MultipartEncoder

# ... code for preparing for upload ...

m = MultipartEncoder(
    fields={'upload_type': upload_type, 'sess_id': sess_id,
            'file_0': ('filename', file handle, 'text/plain')}
    )

r = requests.post(url2, data=m,
                  headers={'Content-Type': m.content_type})
```

For further information see https://toolbelt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/uploading-data.html